# CakePHP : How to Write CronShell command in CronJob

Tags: cakephp, cron

I am new to CakePHP. Please help me on how to write the command for the CronShell inside CronJob. i referred this also  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html but still havn't got any success. Some of the examples i tried -

/home/evand/public_html/site_name/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app "/home/evand/public_html/site_name/app" CronJob test

/home/evand/public_html/site_name/lib/Cake/Console/cake CronJob test -cli /usr/bin -console /cakes/2.x.x/lib/Cake/Console -app /home/evand/public_html/site_name/app

Please tell where i am going wrong or what else command i need to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's much simpler

Those docs appear to be incorrect/outdated. To run a cronjob with cakephp ordinarily all that's required is the following:

```
 * * * * * cd /abs/path/to/app && Console/cake shell_name function_to_run
```

I.e. it's exactly the same as the normal way to run a console command.

Comment: The documentation linked in the question [has now been corrected](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/commit/31a10f1326f921643cf2898cea9615557af8000d).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I run it.

```
* * * * * /var/www/app/app/Console/cakeshell shell_name function_to_run -cli /usr/bin -console /var/www/app/lib/Cake/Console -app /var/www/app/app >> /tmp/logile.log
```

Comment: /bin/sh: /home/evand/public_html/site_name/app/Console/cakeshell: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory....i am getting this error...there is a file exist named cakeshell inside Console folder.

Comment: Remove this character ^M from your file. You created this file on windows machine?

Comment: no i created this file on linux machine..i didn't add ^M. It is showing me in an error.

Comment: i am getting one other error now: - Warning: array_search(): Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/evand/public_html/site_name/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php on line 292..... but second argument of array_search is passing as an array.